# How to move s3 bucket to glacier storage using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-glacier

How to move s3 buckets to glacier storage immediately based on some triggers such as tag change or if there is no activity on the s3 buckets for a given period of time using boto3.
I checked on adding life cycle policy but I can set the transition period only from the date of object creation. But its not suffice for my requirement. I need to move the entire bucket to glacier on nth day if there is no activity for 'n' days

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use [cloud trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-request-identification.html#enable-cloudtrail-logging-for-s3) and monitor the bucket activity.
You can have a lambda function that wake up every N hours, read the cloud trail log for the bucket[s] and if there was no activity for H hours/days/... it will change the storage class of the bucket to the desired storage class.

Comment: could you please explain little more on this @balderman

Comment: sure. AWS can log the access to your s3 buckets. so you can read the logs and see that there was no activity in this bucket for a period of time. At this point you can decide to "move" the bucket to Glacier. Read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html and you will get the idea. Your logic should run periodically as a lambda function